# Why is $HF=L(\omega)$?

Tags: set-theory

So $HF$ are hereditarily finite sets and $L(\omega)=\cup_{n\in\omega}L(n)$, where $L(n)$ are all the definable subsets of $L(n-1)$ with parameters from $L(n-1)$. How does one see that they are equal on an intuitive level? Both are in a certain sense finite, but a priori, one could  imagine this not being an equality.

Any hits would be helpful and many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which definition of $L$ are you using?  The one based on formulas or the one based on Gödel operations?

Comment: @ChadK the one with $L(\alpha+1)=D^{+}(L(\alpha))$ (same as Kunen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that the definition of $L$ based on formulas refers to formulas encoded internally as sequences of characters taken from $\textbf{HF}$.  The truth-value of a formula when its quantifiers and parameters are bounded to a set is defined internally using well-founded recursion.  This implies that a formula can have any finite length where finite refers to the internal definition of finite as being in bijection with some $n\in\omega$.

I assume you know that $V_n$ is finite for all $n\in\omega$.  This follows by induction on $n$ since $|V_0|=0$ and if $|V_n|\in\omega$ then $|V_{n+1}|=|\mathcal{P}(V_n)|=2^{|V_n|}\in\omega$.

The proof that $L_n=V_n$ for $n\in\omega$ is by induction on $n$.

- $L_0=V_0=\emptyset$
- Assume $L_n=V_n$ for some $n\in\omega$.  From the definition of $L_{n+1}$, we have $L_{n+1}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(L_n)=\mathcal{P}(V_n)=V_{n+1}$.  Let $X\subseteq L_n$.  Then $|X|\le|L_n|=|V_n|\in\omega$, i.e. $X$ is a finite set.  Assume $|X|=m\in\omega$ and $X=\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$.  If $m=0$ let $\psi=\bot$.  If $m>0$ let $\psi=\psi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ be the formula $\bigvee_{i=1}^m \left(x=x_i\right)$.  Then
  $$X=\{y\in L_n\colon (L_n,\in)\models\psi(y,a_1,\ldots,a_m)\}$$
  so $X\in L_{n+1}$.  Since $X\in\mathcal{P}(L_n)$ was arbitrary it follows that $V_{n+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_n)=\mathcal{P}(L_n)\subseteq L_{n+1}$.